# Difference between running a script and copying its content and running it on in a terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, environment-variables

I wrote a script named `java_home.sh` with the following content

`export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home`

I ran `./java_home.sh` on the command line, and then I did `echo $JAVA_HOME` - the script did not work, `JAVA_HOME` has not been set.

But copying the content of the script and typing on the terminal
`export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home` does the trick - the environment variable is added.

I'm confused - how is running the script directly different from copying out its content and run it myself? They produce different results.

P.S. I wrote the script with the intention of putting it under `/etc/profile.d` so that it can set the environment variable for all users when the system starts up, so it bothers me that the script is not working.

Comment: shells are different. to run in current shell `. ./java_home.sh`

Comment: You can't export variable in your shell script and get it in your current shell

Comment: @megamonium : The variable **has been** set - in the process which executes the script. You can verify it by doing inside java_home.sh a `printenv JAVA_HOME`. Of course it is not set then in your terminal. If you had sourced the script, hence avoided to create a separated process for it, you would have got your setting in your current shell.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/599445